# Getting "common-lisp:setf common-lisp:list* is undefined" in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am a common-lisp novice. I am having some troubles with the following macro:

**What I have:**

Suppose I have a global variable `*JAN2018*` which is:

```
(:NAME "*JAN2018*" :MONTH "Jan" :YEAR 2018 :EXPENSES (:VALUE NIL :TAGS NIL))
```

If I run

```
(setf (getf *jan2018* :expenses) '(:value 23 :tags '("a" "b")))
```

I get for `*jan2018*`

```
(:NAME "*JAN2018*" :MONTH "Jan" :YEAR 2018 :EXPENSES
 (:VALUE 23 :TAGS '("a" "b")))
```

**The problem:**

Now I have the macro:

```
(defmacro test (sym)
  (setf `(getf ,sym :expenses) '(:value 23 :tags '("a" "b"))))
```

If I run

```
(test *jan2018*)
```

I get (using SBCL)

```
*The function (COMMON-LISP:SETF COMMON-LISP:LIST*) is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]*
```

What I am trying to do is pass a symbol and update one of its fields. Why I am getting this error, and how can I proceed to update the list?

Comment: Did you mean `\`(setf (getf ,sym :expenses) '(:value 23 :tags '("a" "b")))`?

Comment: Ha! I see what is going on. The back quote before getf makes the argument to setf a list. Yes, it seems I meant that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your immediate problem

To debug a macro, use [`macroexpand`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm):

```
(macroexpand-1 '(test *jan2018*))

*** - FUNCTION: undefined function (SETF CONS)
```

This is because you are trying to execute `(setf (list 'getf *jan2018* ...) ...)` at macro expansion time.

I am afraid I cannot offer any specific suggestions because it is not clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish by the macro.

## Your actual problem

You are using an incorrect facility.
Use function instead of macro:

```
(defun test (sym)
  (setf (getf sym :expenses) '(:value 23 :tags '("a" "b"))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I was not fair by not showing the rest of the code. I stripped some code out, which makes my choice of using macro not known. Having said that, your answer exposes my problem at the macro.